# How to make react-collapsed (useCollapse) works into a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-hooks, accordion

I have implemented the react-collapsed library to make a collapse button works. I need to implement this button inside a loop, but I didn't find a way to make it works properly inside a loop. If I press the 1 button to expand 1 section, it expands every section in the loop, so it's not working well.

```
import React from "react";
import AllIcons from "../../ui/icons/all-icons";
import TableSellDataCard from "./TableSellDataCard";
import useCollapse from 'react-collapsed';

const TableContent = ({ data, columns, }) => {
    const { getCollapseProps, getToggleProps, isExpanded } = useCollapse();

    return (
        <>
            {data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <div className="flex px-5 border-b border-gray-form py-2" data-reservation-id={item.id}>
                            {columns.map(() => {
                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        <button className="accordion" {...getToggleProps()}>
                                            {isExpanded ? <AllIcons name="AccordeonArrow" /> : <AllIcons name="AccordeonArrowUp" />}
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <section {...getCollapseProps()}><TableSellDataCard /></section>
                    </ div>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};

export default TableContent;
```

I have one button that toggles the section, but it expands all the sections inside the loop. I need to make it work. Button 1 only opens section 1, and button 2 only opens section 2.

Comment: How many expansion buttons are you rendering per row of data, per section? You've only a single `isExpanded` "state" in the component.